# 'We are soon ready.'

Tags: formality, colloquialisms

I use it as a quick and very informal way to say 'We will soon to be ready.' But a colleague of mine says it is simply wrong. Is he right?

I'm not a native speaker and came up with this phrase on my own, but I found it used here https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/We+are+soon+ready

> Your EPS are soon ready to be archived, mailed or published.

If googled there are thousands of examples.

Comment: You found one example of this very abnormal usage and you think it's the way to go?  It makes sense in "The early turnips are soon ready for use", but most other examples Google finds are obviously not from native English speakers.

Comment: Well, how do I know if it is abnormal? I often use reverso.net for a contextual translation and tend to trust it.

Comment: Even the French translation of that sentence is wrong – _vos EPS **sont** bientôt **prêt**_ is missing some agreement. I don’t know what EPS are supposed to be (perhaps vector files for download from some web service?), but it doesn’t appear to have been properly written in either French or English. The French one is homophone-based and thus quite a likely mistake for a native speaker to make, but the English is not.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for this construct to work, in a certain context: a narration, in present tense. For example,

> The detective approaches the door. He knocks twice. It is soon answered by the butler.

First or third person doesn't matter.

> I open the can of beans. I realize it's rotten, and I soon toss it into the trash.

You can see third person, present tense narration in [another example here](https://thanetwriters.com/essay/voice/tense-narration-present/).

> > Autumn comes. Gregory goes back to his tutor; his reluctance is clear enough, though little about Gregory is clear to him. ‘What is it,’ he asks him, ‘what’s wrong?’ The boy won’t say. [...]
> >
> > Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel
>
> Mantel utilises the constant now of present tense, even when time is passing, to keep the reader engaged and ploughing forward through the story.

Outside of a narration of that sort, however, it's not going to sound right. This context is a conversation, not a narration. You're telling someone what you will do in the (near) future. First person, future tense is the appropriate choice: "we will soon be ready" or "we will be ready soon" (a slightly more common word order).

Source, aside from the link: native speaker

Answer (score 0):

Using "soon" implies you are talking about the future, so you need the future tense to go with it - "We will soon be ready" or "We will be ready soon." I think this is the case for any adjective; you could say "I will be happy tomorrow" but not "I am happy tomorrow." Verbs are different; you can just as naturally say "I will be leaving tomorrow" as "I am leaving tomorrow." Your EPS example is just wrong, I think.

You could say "We are soon to be ready" though it sounds a little archaic.